# Eclipse - GWT - Java - MySQL - how to catch an exception correctly

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, gwt

I have finally completed my application (Eclipse, GWT, Java, MySQL, Tomcat) and it has been uploaded onto a server (I have someone else uploading the application onto a server). However, there seems to be an issue with the server installation and my code is not sending back any errors.

For instance: when a new account is created the following message is displayed "Your account has been created. Please contact a leader to associate youth members to it." however the database is not updated. It seems that I am not catching an exception correctly.

My code is:

Client side call:

```
AsyncCallback<User> callback = new CreationHandler<User>();
rpc.createUser(textBoxAccount.getText(), textBoxPassword.getText(), null, null, null, callback);
```

Server side:

```
public User createUser(String userName, String pass, String level, String pack, java.sql.Date archived) {
    User user = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String pw_hash = BCrypt.hashpw(pass, BCrypt.gensalt());
    try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(
          "INSERT INTO at_accounts (acc_email_address, acc_password, acc_enabled) " +
                  "VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
      ps.setString(1, userName);
      ps.setString(2, pw_hash);
      ps.setString(3, "1");
      ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      //do stuff on fail
        System.out.println("SQLException createUser 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        user = null;
    }
    finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException createUser 2.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException createUser 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return user;
}
```

Client side:

```
class CreationHandler<T> implements AsyncCallback<User> {
    //Create the account.
    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        Window.alert("RPC call failed - CreationHandler - Notify Administrator.");  
    }
    public void onSuccess(User result) {
        Window.alert("Your account has been created. Please contact a leader to associate youth members to it.");

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Glyn

Hi JonK,

Is this what you mean please?

```
public User createUser(String userName, String pass, String level, String pack, java.sql.Date archived) {
    User user = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String pw_hash = BCrypt.hashpw(pass, BCrypt.gensalt());
    try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(
          "INSERT INTO at_accounts (acc_email_address, acc_password, acc_enabled) " +
                  "VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
      ps.setString(1, userName);
      ps.setString(2, pw_hash);
      ps.setString(3, "1");
      ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      //do stuff on fail
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("SQLException createUser 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        user = null;
    }
    finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                try {
                    conn.rollback();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("SQLException createUser 2.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                try {
                    conn.rollback();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("SQLException createUser 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("SQLException createUser 4 - commit error.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return user;
}
```

This is the updated code with the suggested error handling:

```
package org.AwardTracker.server;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

import org.AwardTracker.client.BCrypt;

import org.AwardTracker.client.Account;
import org.AwardTracker.client.AccountAndCubs;
import org.AwardTracker.client.AccountCubAssociation;
import org.AwardTracker.client.AwardAward;
import org.AwardTracker.client.AwardDescription;
import org.AwardTracker.client.AwardStockDtls;
import org.AwardTracker.client.DBConnection;
import org.AwardTracker.client.SectionDetails;
import org.AwardTracker.client.Stock;
import org.AwardTracker.client.User;
import org.AwardTracker.client.ViewData;
import org.AwardTracker.client.YMATask;
import org.AwardTracker.client.YMAwards;
import org.AwardTracker.client.YMandAward;
import org.AwardTracker.client.YMAwardDetails;
import org.AwardTracker.client.YouthMember;
import org.AwardTracker.client.YouthMemberAwards;
import org.AwardTracker.client.YthMmbrSectDtls;

import org.AwardTracker.server.Base64Encode2;

public class MySQLConnection extends RemoteServiceServlet implements DBConnection {
//TODO
//  •Use JNDI to bind the data source.
//  •Close the connection as soon as its done in finally block.
//  •Manage the connection in single class for whole application.
//  •Initialise the data source at application start up single time.
//  •Store the database configuration outside the JAVA code somewhere in properties file or web.xml.
//  •Create an abstract class for AsyncCallback that will handle all the failures happened while performing any RPC calls.
//  •Extend this abstract class for all RPC AsyncCallback but now you have to just provide implementation of onSuccess() only.
//  •Don't handle any exception in service implementation just throw it to client or if handled then re-throw some meaning full exception back to client.
//  •Add throws in all the methods for all the RemoteService interfaces whenever needed.

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Connection conn = null;
private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/awardtracker";
private String user = "awtrack";
private String pass = "************";

public MySQLConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //NEVER catch exceptions like this

        System.out.println("Error connecting to database - not good eh");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Store and retrieve data used by Views within the application
//This allows us to securely pass parameters between Views.
private ViewData viewData = null;

public ViewData setViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel,
        String ymId, String awId, String adGroup) {

    viewData = new ViewData();

    viewData.setaccountId(accountId);
    viewData.setaccountLevel(accountLevel);
    viewData.setymId(ymId);
    viewData.setawId(awId);
    viewData.setadGroup(adGroup);

    return viewData;
}

public ViewData getViewData() {
    return viewData;
}


public User authenticateUser(String accID, String userName, String pass, String level, String pack, Integer enabled, java.sql.Date archived) {

    User user = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String stored_hash = null;

    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(
          "SELECT * " +
          "FROM at_accounts " +
          "WHERE acc_email_address = ?");

        ps.setString(1, userName);

        result = ps.executeQuery();

        while (result.next()) {
            user = new User(result.getString(1), result.getString(2), result.getString(3), result.getString(4), result.getString(5), result.getInt(6), result.getDate(7));
            stored_hash = result.getString(3);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e2) {
            System.out.println("Error rolling back transaction for authenticateUser.");
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("SQLException in authenticateUser.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (stored_hash != null) {
        if (BCrypt.checkpw(pass, stored_hash))  {
        } else {
            user = null;
        }
    }else{
        user = null;
    }

    return user;
}

//Disable or enable Account
public User disableUser(String user, Integer enabled) {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(
              "UPDATE at_accounts " +
              "SET acc_enabled=? " +
              "WHERE acc_email_address=?");

      ps.setInt(1, enabled);
      ps.setString(2, user);
      ps.executeUpdate();
      conn.commit();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e2) {
            System.out.println("Error rolling back transaction for createUser.");
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("SQLException in createUser.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public User duplicateUser(String userName, String pass, String level, String pack, java.sql.Date archived) {
    User user = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(
          "SELECT * " +
          "FROM at_accounts " +
          "WHERE acc_email_address = ?");

      ps.setString(1, userName);

      result = ps.executeQuery();
      while (result.next()) {
         user = new User(null, result.getString(2), null, null, null, null, null);
      }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e2) {
            System.out.println("Error rolling back transaction for duplicateUser.");
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("SQLException in duplicateUser.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return user;
}

public User createUser(String userName, String pass, String level, String pack, java.sql.Date archived) {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String pw_hash = BCrypt.hashpw(pass, BCrypt.gensalt());
    try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(
          "INSERT INTO at_accounts (acc_email_address, acc_password, acc_enabled) " +
                  "VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
      ps.setString(1, userName);
      ps.setString(2, pw_hash);
      ps.setString(3, "1");
      ps.executeUpdate();
      conn.commit();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e2) {
            System.out.println("Error rolling back transaction for createUser.");
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("SQLException in createUser.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is three any Exception logged?

Comment: Hi Braj, I have asked this question of the person setting up the server and have not heard back yet. I have to be patient as he is doing the set up in his own time as a favour to our Group. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: I will take this one step at a time. I have now posted the change with the new error handling. Please check to ensure this is what you mean. Next I will move error handling to an abstract class (need to pass parameters to it so I know which class is returning the error), look at log4j and move the DB login to XML. Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't committing the transaction to the database. In order for the changes made by `ps.executeUpdate();` to become permanent, you will need to call [`conn.commit();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit%28%29) after the update.

Similarly, in your `catch` block you should call [`conn.rollback();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback%28%29) so as to avoid the possibility of dud data being inserted into the database.

I can't see the declaration for `conn`, so I assume it's a member variable whatever class `createUser` belongs to. You might want to consider changing the `Connection` to be a local in the method, so that you don't forget to close it once it's no longer needed (which *should* be once you've committed).

Lastly, if you're using Java 7+, you can take advantage of [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to handle the closing of your `PreparedStatement`, `ResultSet` and `Connection` for you (although you don't appear to be using the `ResultSet` for anything, so consider removing it from the method).

---

Here are two examples of what I meant (one for Java 6 and below, and one for Java 7 and later utilising `try-with-resources`:

### Java 6-

```
public void createUser(String userName, String pass) {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    String pw_hash = BCrypt.hashpw(pass, BCrypt.gensalt());
    try {
        // Acquire a Connection here rather than using a member variable
        // NOTE: See Braj's answer for a better way of doing this
        // using his ConnectionUtil class.
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/awardtracker", "awtrack", 
                    "**************");

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO at_accounts (acc_email_address, acc_password,"
                  + " acc_enabled) "
              + "VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        ps.setString(1, userName);
        ps.setString(2, pw_hash);
        ps.setString(3, "1");
        ps.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e2) {
            System.out.println("Error rolling back transaction.");
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("SQLException createUser 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException createUser 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Error closing Connection.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Java 7+

```
private static final String INSERT_STATEMENT =
        "INSERT INTO at_accounts (acc_email_address, acc_password, "
      + "acc_enabled) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

public void createUser(String userName, String pass) {
    String pw_hash = BCrypt.hashpw(pass, BCrypt.gensalt());

    // NOTE: See Braj's answer for a better way of getting Connections.
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost/awardtracker", "awtrack",
            "**************");
         PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_STATEMENT);) {

        try {
            ps.setString(1, userName);
            ps.setString(2, pw_hash);
            ps.setString(3, "1");
            ps.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            try {
                conn.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException e2) {
                System.out.println("Error rolling back transaction.");
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("SQLException createUser 1.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error connecting to DB.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In both examples I have removed unused method parameters (why have them there if you're doing nothing with them?) and have changed the return type to `void`. I did this because in its current form your method will *always* `return null` (you initialise your `User` object to `null`, then do nothing with it to change its value, then return it at the end).

You should also consider using a logging framework such as [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) to handle your exception logging rather than relying on `printStackTrace()`. See [Why is exception.printStackTrace() considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469316/why-is-exception-printstacktrace-considered-bad-practice) for more information on why `printStackTrace()` isn't recommended.

Comment: Hi JoinK, Thank you. I have entered my revised code above. Is this correct /what you meant please? Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Hi JonK, I have updated my code above with your error handling. If this is OK then I will move all error handling into a single class as suggested by Braj. I will then look at using log4j and moving the connections to XML. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Hi JonK, When testing this the user is successfully created however an error is generated you cannot commit when auto commit is yes. So I have removed the "conn.commit();" line. Is this the correct thing to do or should I turn auto commit off (where is this)? Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Glyn - you should probably turn off auto-commit yes. [This article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit) shows you how to turn it off.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. I take it that the rest of what I am doing is correct. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: It looks a bit better now (though I would still make `conn` a local variable instead of a member variable, tidy up the unused method parameters and change the return type to `void`). Also, if you're using Java 7+ you no longer need to explicitly call `Class.forName(String)` to load the driver, so you might be able to get rid of that too.

Comment: Hi JonK, I also very much appreciate your efforts and assistance. I will work through this and implement as I can. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Hi JonK, "Baby Steps". I now understand the void and have successfully made the change for createUser method. I will now implement this in the other methods that do not return a value. Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 1):

Points to rememeber:

- Use JNDI to bind the data source.
- Close the connection as soon as its done in `finally` block.
- Manage the connection in single class for whole application.
- Initialize the data source at application start up single time.
- Store the database configuration outside the JAVA code somewhere in properties file or web.xml.

I have already shared a sample code for **ConnectionUtil** class that's sole purpose is to manage the connection in single class using **JNDI lookup** and it can log that how many connections are opened for what time in the application?

Please have a look at below posts:

- [“Servlet” (server-side) initialization code in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999830/servlet-server-side-initialization-code-in-gwt?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [No operations allowed after statement closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323653/no-operations-allowed-after-statement-closed/23323793#23323793)

---

> GWT - how to catch an exception correctly?

- Create an abstract class for `AsyncCallback` that will handle all the failures happened while performing any RPC calls.
- Extend this abstract class for all RPC `AsyncCallback` but now you have to just provide implementation of `onSuccess()` only.
- Don't handle any exception in service implantation just throw it to client or if handled then re-throw some meaning full exception back to client.
- Add `throws` in all the methods for all the `RemoteService` interfaces whenever needed.

Sample code:

```
// single class to handle all the AsyncCallback failure
public abstract class MyAsyncCallback<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        // all the failure are catched here
        // prompt user if needed
        // on failure message goes to here
        // send the failure message back to server for logging
    }

}

// do it for all the RPC AsyncCallback
public class CreationHandler<T> extends MyAsyncCallback<T> {
    //Create the account.
    public void onSuccess(T result) {
        // on success message goes to here
    }
}

// use in this way
AsyncCallback<User> callback = new CreationHandler<User>();
```

Comment: Hi Braj, Thank you for this. It will take me some time to digest this and work it out. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: @Glyn I have updated my post to handler all the RPC exception in GWT in single class.

Comment: Hi Braj, Thanks for this. I have updated my code to include the correct error handling from JonK. Next I will move the error handling to your single class. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Hi Braj, I went to include your code above on the server side then it struck me that this is the same code I am using on the client side. I think I totally miss understood what you were saying. So I think I am doing the right thing on the client side in capturing messages sent back from the server side and displaying error messages when appropriate. All I need to do is get my server side code correct. Is that right? Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Suppose you are making 100 RPC calls with different type of AsyncCallbacks then you have to override `onFailure()` method for all the calls but by extending single class `MyAsyncCallback` that I provided in my post will responsible for `onFailure()` method, you don'tn need to implement `onFailure()` for all 100 RPC calls of different type of AsyncCallbacks. I hope you got it now. I summarize it again **single `onFailure()` method for all the RPC calls for whole application.**

Comment: Hi Braj, I very much appreciate all your help and I apologise if I am a little slow. I will persist in understanding and implementing this. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: My pleasure. Happy leaning.